# Why this.add.group({}) works well in tutorial but not in my game?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm making a game with Phaser and I'm trying to group tiles together and
render them out like this:

My code:

```
let gameScene = new Phaser.Scene('Game');

gameScene.preload = function() {
    this.load.image('background', 'assets/backgrounds/beach/game_background_1.png');
    this.load.image('tile', 'assets/images/tile.png');
    

}

gameScene.create = function() {
    let bg = this.add.sprite(0, 0, 'background').setOrigin(0, 0);
    this.tiles = this.add.group({
        key: 'tile',
        repeat: 5,
        setXY: {
            x: 150,
            y: this.sys.game.config.height - 80,
            stepX: 150,
            stepY: this.sys.game.config.height - 80,
        }
    });

    Phaser.Actions.ScaleXY(this.tiles.getChildren(), -0.5, -0.5);

}

gameScene.update = function() {

}
```

code in tutorial:

```
gameScene.preload = function(){
  // load images
  ...
  ...
  this.load.image('enemy', 'assets/dragon.png');
  ...
};

gameScene.create = function() {
    this.enemies = this.add.group({
      key: 'enemy',
      repeat: 5,
      setXY: {
        x: 90,
        y: 100,
        stepX: 80,
        stepY: 20
    }
  });

  Phaser.Actions.ScaleXY(this.enemies.getChildren(), -0.4, -0.4);
```

`this.add.group({})` works fine in tutorial but when I use it in my game I get only 1 tile rendered. What's happening here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the problem is the `stepY`, that value seems too be much to big. `this.sys.game.config.height - 80` will put the second tile outside the display area, thats why you see only one tile. *([Here is the link to the documentation](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.70.0/Phaser.Types.GameObjects.Group.GroupCreateConfig) for more details on the config object for a phaser group)*

**Solution:** Try setting  a smaller value for the property `stepY`, than you should see the tiles.